# Remove chapter from whole occupied page and center list of tables, list of figures, and table of contents

Tags: thesis

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{mitthesis}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lgrind}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{cases}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\def\files{all}
\def\all{all}
\ifx\files\all \typeout{Including all files.} \else \typeout{Including only \files.} \includeonly{\files} \fi

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\include{cover1}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\mainmatter\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection. #1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection. #1}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{List of Tables}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables{}
\newpage

\include{Chap1_V1}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\include{Chap2_V1}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

%\include{Refrences_V1}
\appendix
\include{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not having access to mittheses class I couldn't run your MWE.  You can remove a lot of the extra pages by removing the [twoside] option.  Everything else probably comes from tocloft (which overwrites the document class definitions).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the `mitthesis` class and I'm not really sure what you are asking. The following MWE may help you on your way (or may not).

```
% centertocprob.tex SE 528927 Center ToC et al

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% centered Large Bold ToC title
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\Large\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

% page number after chapter title and centered 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\hfil\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{ \textperiodcentered}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{Second chapter with a longer title}
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

The above centers a ToC title and roughly centers the chapter entries in the ToC. Please read the `tocloft` documentation to get an idea. If the above is any help then you will have to do similar things for the entries (section etc) for the ToC and for entries in the LoF and Lot.

Good luck. GOM